# Use sqlserver to get different MO according to time period

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, pivot

Use sqlserver to get different MO according to time period.

Source table `route`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].route(
    [sfcno] varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    [time] [datetime]NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

insert into route(sfcno ,time)
values (10,'08:00'),
       (10,'08:10'),
       (11,'08:30'),
       (22,'09:10'),
       (33,'10:10'),
       (44,'11:10'),
       (555,'11:30')
```

I want to get the following

```
08:00-09:00   09:00-10:00   10:00-11:00   11:00-12:00
10,11         22            33            44,555
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find that it would make more sense to put the results in rows than in columns:

```
select 
    format(datepart(hour, time), '00') + ':00-' 
        +  format(datepart(hour, time) + 1, '00') + ':00' as timeslot, 
    string_agg(sfcno, ',') within group(order by sfcno) sfcnos
from route 
group by datepart(hour, time)
```

```
timeslot    | sfcnos  
:---------- | :-------
08:00-09:00 | 10,10,11
09:00-10:00 | 22      
10:00-11:00 | 33      
11:00-12:00 | 44,555
```

If you really want columns, then you need conditional aggregation - it gets longer to type:

```
select 
    string_agg(case when datepart(hour, time) =  8 then sfcno end, ',') within group(order by sfcno) as time_slot_08_09,
    string_agg(case when datepart(hour, time) =  9 then sfcno end, ',') within group(order by sfcno) as time_slot_09_10,
    string_agg(case when datepart(hour, time) = 10 then sfcno end, ',') within group(order by sfcno) as time_slot_10_11,
    string_agg(case when datepart(hour, time) = 11 then sfcno end, ',') within group(order by sfcno) as time_slot_11_12
from route
```

```
time_slot_08_09 | time_slot_09_10 | time_slot_10_11 | time_slot_11_12
:-------------- | :-------------- | :-------------- | :--------------
10,10,11        | 22              | 33              | 44,555
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b1a2656237facb20e794ef76e808ed40)**

Comment: thanks ,but i need distenct sfcno.if you have better answer,can you tell me ?

Answer (score 0):

What you wanted to get is pivoting which converts rows to columns due to the defined rule. Prefer using Dynamic pivoting as illustrated below :

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(
                                   CONCAT(
                                          FORMAT(DATEPART(hour, time), '00') + ':00',
                                          '-',
                                          FORMAT(DATEPART(hour, time) + 1, '00') + ':00'
                                          )
                                   ) AS time
                        FROM route
                     
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


SET  @query = 
 N'SELECT '+ @cols + N' 
     FROM
     (
      SELECT STRING_AGG(sfcno, '','') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sfcno) AS sfcno, time
        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT sfcno,  
                      CONCAT(
                             FORMAT(DATEPART(hour, time), ''00'') + '':00-'',
                             FORMAT(DATEPART(hour, time) + 1, ''00'') + '':00''
                             ) AS time
                 FROM route ) r
       GROUP BY time 
      ) q
    PIVOT 
    (
     MAX(sfcno) FOR time IN (' + @cols + N')
    ) p '

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b2e77252e06c9a33e9e19f40f64aa52f)</kbd>

Comment: sorry，The version of my sqlserver is 2012